# How to query for ObjectIds in feathersjs that are normal fields?

Tags: mongodb, feathersjs

I have a collection of product variants, i.e., different versions of the same product.  There's a separate product collection.  Variant documents have a product_id field, which holds the ObjectId of the corresponding product document in the product collection; its type is ObjectId.  All searches on this field return 0 records.  If I change the type to String, I can search successfully.

The service processing these searches uses feathersjs.  I thought the correct way to structure my query for feathers would be this:

```
  const params = {
    'params': {
      'query': {
        'product_id': ObjectId(productId)
      }
    }
  };
```

When I do that, the params arrive at the server like this:

```
{ 
    query: { 
        product_id: { 
            id: '\\îÄ¦ ;ÌúgÄ' 
        } 
    } 
}
```

That's what I see if I console.log the value at the client side, so I'm confident that the transport is working correctly.

Like I said, if I change the data type of a value to a String, I can get the search results I expect by doing:

```
  const params = {
    'params': {
      'query': {
        'product_id': productId
      }
    }
  };
```

I'm stumped here and don't know what else to try.  I'm sure this is possible because I can query for `_id` fields with no problems.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: No, we're not.  Just regular MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion to the internal type should happen on the server. This can be done in a hook [similar to the one from this issue](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/757):

```
const { ObjectID } = require('mongodb');

module.exports = function() {
  return async context => {
    const { query = {} } = context.params;

    if(query. product_id) {
      query.product_id = new ObjectID(query._id);
    }

    return context;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  What's the difference between context.params and context.arguments?

Comment: `context.params` is the [params from the service call](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#params). `arguments` is the complete method call argument list.